# CSS uses opacity,then scroll the table,the td of tbody covered the th of thead,why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use this css to set the table disabled.

```
.disabledDiv {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

I must use this transparency.

When I scroll the scroll bar,the td of tbody covered the th of thead,likes this:[image]

I don't want the th to be covered,here is my [code link in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dws23tr1/1/).

How to make th not be covered?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your CSS, your javascript is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gerard mentioned, you have eventListener for scroll event that shifts thead section. Solution - just remove js part for thead section.

```
document.getElementById("table_reach_condition_appoint").addEventListener("scroll", function(){
           var translate = "translate(0,"+this.scrollTop+"px)";
           this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate;
        });
```